# 'Undefined variable' error when running tcsh script

Tags: linux, foreach, tcsh

I am trying to execute each script that has "~SAC" at the end of their filenames. For such purpose, I wrote tc shell script using "foreach" like the code below.

However, when I execute it by typing ./run.tcsh, it only shows that
"tmpdir: Undefined variable". ('tmpdir' is the directory which has all the files which I want to apply my code)
How could I resolve this problem?

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set inputdir=tmpdir
foreach sacfile(`find $tmpdir -name '*.SAC'`)
  echo "processing $sacfile"
  classic_LR $sacfile
end
```

The name of my execution file is 'classic_LR' and it is executed by following form of input;

```
./classic_LR sacfile
```

where 'sacfile' refers to the name of file I want to apply classic_LR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable is `inputdir` and not `tmpdir`.

So, change

```
foreach sacfile(`find $tmpdir -name '*.SAC'`)
```

to

```
foreach sacfile(`find $inputdir -name '*.SAC'`)
```

Comment: I checked that the message "Undefined~" does not appear after editing it. However, it just returns the message "Usage: classic_LR filename.sac output.txt". Am I missing something? How should I edit the code to make it execute? Do I have to add the txt file to print output in my code?

Comment: That seems like a different problem - something specific to your C code.

Comment: Okay. I will check that myself.